# Use uuid.uuid4() to create new file

Tags: python

How do you concatenate the uuid.uuid4() value with a literal when creating a file?  The below isn't correct but should illustrate what I'm attempting to do...

```
fo = open(uuid.uuid4() + ".txt", "wb")
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to convert the `uuid` to a `str`:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
'13eb9327-f40e-4ef1-8020-1c36af1b4b70.txt'
```

Answer (score 3):

This version doesn't include the `-` in the string

```
fo = open(uuid.uuid4().hex + ".txt", "wb")
```

It's often a good idea to open the file using a context manager

```
with open(uuid.uuid4().hex + ".txt", "wb") as fo:
    # do stuff with fo
    # fo will be closed automatically
```

Here's an example in a loop

```
for item in data:
    with open(uuid.uuid4().hex + ".txt", "wb") as fo:
        fo.write(item)
```

Comment: I'm executing a loop where I create a new file (using the open command then I write to it then I close it and repeat that process.  Would a context manager be appropriate in this scenario?

Comment: @c12, sure, just put the with inside the loop